# PHP: evaluate values inside string

Tags: php, string, eval

I have this string ($query) returning from preg_replace

```
'SELECT ({$array["sum"]}/ 5)'
```

how can i evaluate it, so that the result would be `'SELECT (100/5)'` for example !

I tried

```
eval($query)
```

But with no success!

Do you have a better idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're not using eval right:

```
$evaluated = eval("return $query;");
```

take care you do not have any syntax errors. also you just might do it wrong when you build SQL queries this way. Just saying, I hope you're old enough.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this worked fine!!
I will definitely add more security precautions.
The final string will actually look something like this :)
input example: `"SELECT ({total_price.total_id}/ 5)"`
output: `"SELECT (".mysqli_real_escape_string($this->app_array["application"]["sql"]["total_price"]["total_id"])."/ 5)"`

Answer (score 1):

Just replace the single quotes `'` with double quotes `"`.

```
"SELECT ({$array["sum"]}/ 5)"
```

And it is not a good idea to use `eval()` during `$_POST` or while getting input from users. Just a suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Just glue them together with the `.` operator:

```
$array['sum'] = 100;
echo 'SELECT (' . $array['sum' ] . ' / 5)';
```

will result in:

```
SELECT (100 / 5)
```

Comment: The string is coming right from a preg_replace :) I will try to produce a similar string and evaluate it though. So thanks :)